# Using a global array like a pointer, C

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

**Objective**

I have a global TX array, and a CRC function that has to progress through this array. The CRC function should not process the first byte. To avoid this I am trying to increment the array by doing TX++. This is causing problems.

**Problem**

Please take a quick look at the code below:

```
void Send_To_Manager(void)
{   
    TX[0] = 0x55;
    TX[1] = 0x00;
    TX[2] = 0x01;
    TX[3] = 0x00;
    TX[4] = COMMON_COMMAND;     
    TX++;
    TX[5] = CRC8(TX,4);
    TX[6] = CO_RD_VERSION;
    TX += 5;
    TX[7] = CRC8(TX,1);
    TX -= 6;
    UART_TX(8);     
}
```

I would like to blind the CRC8 function of the first byte in the TX array. By executing TX++, I am expecting the TX[0] to be 0x00. However I am getting the error:

*error: wrong type argument to increment*

I am also getting the errors for TX += 5; and TX -= 6 as:

*error: incompatible types in assignment*

I played around with this, so instead if the function has an array such as:

```
void Send_To_Manager(unsigned char data[100])
{
    data++; 
}
```

The above works as intended.

**Questions**

- Why can I do this for Function based arrays and not Global arrays?
- If I do wish to do this for global arrays how can I do it?
- How would you prefer to achieve the above objective?

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can I do this for Function based arrays and not Global arrays?

Arrays as function parameters are decayed to pointers, `data` in your example is just a local variable with type `unsigned char*`, you can modify it as you want. `TX` however is (I suppose) a static array and not a modifiable pointer.

> If I do wish to do this for global arrays how can I do it?

First, **make sure that's really what you want to do**. Modifying the value of `TX` will not only affect the call to `CRC8` but also all the following instructions that are dereferencing the value of `TX`.

As instance, `TX++; TX[5] = CRC8(TX,4);` is equivalent to `TX[6] = CRC8(TX+1,4); TX++;`.

If you don't want that side effect, don't change the value of `TX`, just use `CRC8(TX+1,4)` and `CRC8(TX+5,4)`.

However, if that's really what you want, then you'll have to use a temporary pointer :

```
void Send_To_Manager(void)
{   
    char* myTX = TX;
    myTX[0] = 0x55;
    myTX[1] = 0x00;
    myTX[2] = 0x01;
    myTX[3] = 0x00;
    myTX[4] = COMMON_COMMAND;     
    myTX++;
    myTX[5] = CRC8(myTX,4);
    myTX[6] = CO_RD_VERSION;
    myTX += 5;
    myTX[7] = CRC8(myTX,1);
    myTX -= 6;
    UART_TX(8);     
}
```

If the increments of `myTX` have to be kept for the next call to `Send_To_Manager`, you could make it static to the function. If the modifications of `TX` have to be reflected in the whole program, then you have a strong architecture issue.

> How would you prefer to achieve the above objective?

If the modification of `TX` must only impact the `Send_To_Manager` function, the above solutions will do fine. In other cases, you'll have to rethink your program architecture. A possible solution could be to pass the current progressing state as parameters instead of using a global state variable.

```
char* Send_To_Manager(char* currentTX)
{   
    currentTX[0] = 0x55;
    ...
    currentTX[4] = COMMON_COMMAND;     
    currentTX++;
    ...
    return currentTX;
}
```

Comment: I have noticed an additional mistake to what I have been trying to do.
instead of TX[5] = CRC8(TX,4); it should actually be TX++; temp = CRC8(TX,4) ; TX--; TX[5] =  temp;

Comment: @Volcano In that case you don't have to modify `TX` at all, just call `CRC8(TX+1, 4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to alter the array reference itself, why not:

```
TX[5] = CRC8(TX+1,4);
TX[7] = CRC8(TX+6,1);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `TX[6] = CRC8(TX+1,4)` and `TX[13] = CRC8(TX+6,1)` in order to reflect the modifications of `TX` value ?

Comment: You're right, zakinster, and that sort of confusion is precisely why it's a bad idea to mess with your array references.